# How do i create a picture that locks a page's content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I want to create a website similar to this website: 
http://www.ssangar.com/#home
My website will have a fullscreen picture similar to the one in the link above. However i want to make the first picture lock all other contents when the website first load. To unlock the content, viewer needs to click on a certain button. Upon clicking, the picture will disappear in a stylish manner.

My basic codes so far for the image and the style is here:

```
<body>
    <div class="foreground">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>What i am up to</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.foreground { 
  background-image: url('./Img/Foreground1.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

So my question is how do i make the first picture lock all other contents? Including hiding the scroll-bar. Is it possible to do with a single-page website?

Comment: That website is not locking the contents (including scrollbars) but customized the scrollbar...

Comment: What you're looking for can be solved with a modal box. You will have to do some research to see what works best for you, but that's where you should start.